# Write multiple Lines with Renci.SshNet.SshClient in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh

I'm asking how to write multiple Lines of code to my Gate (Firewall) with the RenciSSH command library.
Right now I'm creating ShellStreams, but it seems that how I'm doing it no Line gets executed/sent to the the Gate.

```
$client = New-Object Renci.SshNet.SshClient($HostIP,$User,$Password)
$client.Connect()
$stream = $client.CreateShellStream("Programm",0,0,0,0,1000)

$stream.Write("Command")
stream.flush()

$client.disconnect()
```

The Problem could also be how I create the ShellStream, because to be honest, I don't know how to interpret the Numbers.

And yes, SSH is enabled.

Comment: `CreateShellStream(string terminalName, uint columns, uint rows, uint width, uint height, int bufferSize)`, according to the documentation. If you google `Renci.SshNet.SshClient` you should find all the necessary info.

Comment: Thanks @notjustme, but that sadly doesen't fix my problem. Do you know what else it could be?

Comment: I haven't studied the library but `WriteLine(<your string>)` might be what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@notjustme found the Answer:

WriteLine is the one that works.
Just create a ShellStream and then write with WriteLine even without the flush and it works. So here's the Answer:

```
$client = New-Object Renci.SshNet.SshClient($HostIP,$User,$Password)
$client.Connect()
$stream = $client.CreateShellStream("Programm",0,0,0,0,1000)

$stream.WriteLine("Command")

$client.disconnect()
```